# Automatically close the correct XML / HTML tag on typing </

Tags: html, xml, notepad++

Does anyone know of a Notepad++ plugin that will automatically close the correct balanced tag upon typing `</` ?

e.g. if i had typed

```
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
</
```

I would like to have the plugin auto-generate / auto-complete the closing tag to be `</ul>`

The `Tag auto-close` function of the `XML-tools` plugin and the `Auto-close XHTML/XML <Tag>` function of the `TextFx` plugin both seem to just support automatically generating a close tag immediately following the open tag, at the time that the open tag is typed. This is **not** what i'm looking for. I'm after a function that fires upon the event of typing `</`. i.e. as you are attempting to close a tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try `TextFX characters`. Make sure you set language as HTML/XML.

Comment: I see that TextFX has a feature in `settings` called `Auto-close XHTML/XML <Tag>` but this appears to do the same as the `Tag auto-close` function of the `XML-tools` plugin, discussed above. Which function in TextFX should I be looking at?